Forming 'UnsafeRawPointer' to a variable of type '[T]'; this is likely incorrect because 'T' may contain an object reference
I inherited some code and have been trying for some time to silence the warning for Forming 'UnsafeRawPointer' to a variable of type '[T]'; this is likely incorrect because 'T' may contain an object reference. The warning is for the pointer: array on the last line. The code itself works, or seems to do, as the bytes written may be read back later without error. But I want to do it right. Does anyone know what this is referring to?
func writeBytes(pointer: UnsafeRawPointer, length: Int, documentName: String) -> Bool {
        let data = Data(bytes: pointer, count: length)
        do {
            try data.write(to: docsDir.appending(path: documentName))
            return true
        } catch {
            print("Error writing bytes for file \(documentName):", error)
            return false
        }
    }
    
func writeBytesFrom<T>(array: [T], documentName: String) -> Bool {
        return writeBytes(pointer: array, length: array.count * MemoryLayout<T>.stride, documentName: documentName)
    }


Related post of mine.

Actually I think the warning is quite justified. You are making an assumption that T is a trivial type. If T is a reference type for example, writeBytes would write the references (pointers) to the actual instances (which will not necessarily "be read back later without error"), and not the properties of each instance. I'd recommend making this clear in the documentation or something.

In addition to the issues Sweeper pointed out, there a much more fundamental problem here. Even for trivial values (structs/enums composed of other trivial structs/enums), Swift doesn't guarantee that the in-memory layout of values is stable across app launches, let alone between machines. E.g. there could be difference in integer endianness, 64 bit vs 32 bit, etc. To serialize values to a file, you should use a more intentional serialization method, like JSON, YAML, XML, protobuffs, etc.

Looking at some discussions on forums.swift.org withUnsafePointer(to:) seems to be a way to handle this
func writeBytesFrom<T>(array: [T], documentName: String) -> Bool {
    withUnsafePointer(to: array) { pointer in
        writeBytes(pointer: pointer, length: array.count * MemoryLayout<T>.stride, documentName: documentName)
    }
}


I think you're right, thanks.

I would suggest using array.withUnsafeBtyes { pointer in ... } instead (docs). It'll give you a UnsaferawBufferPointer, whose count property will be the correct number of bytes (so you don't need to manually multiply by the stride). Furthermore, it doesn't rely on Swift's special behaviour of bridging Arrays into pointers, which I personally think is too magical and should mostly be avoided.

@Alexander the problem is that Data(bytes...) needs an UnsafeRawPointer and using the array.withUnsafeBytes... gives me the error Cannot convert value of type 'UnsafeRawBufferPointer' to expected argument type 'UnsafeRawPointer'

@johnbakers You just need to use its baseAddress property

@Alexander beautiful, thanks, that worked

@johnbakers In case you missed it, have a look at the comment I left on your main post above

So maybe post a more correct answer and mark that as accepted instead of this one?

@johnbakers if this is not the correct answer, which I suspect it isn’t, then please remove the accepted mark so I can remove it.

in Swift 6.0:
func writeBytesFrom<T: BitwiseCopyable>(array: [T], documentName: String) -> Bool {
    return writeBytes(pointer: array, length: array.count * MemoryLayout<T>.stride, documentName: documentName)
}


I would suggest using Array.withUnsafeBtyes instead:
// Danger! This is really fragile!
func writeBytesFrom<T>(array: [T], documentName: String) -> Bool {
    array.withUnsafeBtyes { buffer in
        writeBytes(pointer: buffer.baseAddress, length: buffer.count, documentName: documentName)
    }
}

The UnsafeRawBufferPointer that it gives you will have a count property  with correct number of bytes pre-calculated for you (so you don't need to manually multiply by the stride).
Furthermore, it doesn't rely on Swift's special behaviour of bridging Arrays into pointers, which I personally think is too magical and should mostly be avoided.

All that being said, this is still really fragile and borderline wrong code.
In addition to the issues Sweeper pointed out, there a much more fundamental problem here.
Even for trivial values (structs/enums composed of other trivial structs/enums), Swift doesn't guarantee that the in-memory layout of values is stable across app launches, let alone between machines. E.g. there could be difference in integer endianness, 64 bit vs 32 bit, etc. To serialize values to a file, you should use a more intentional serialization method, like JSON, YAML, XML, protobuffs, etc.
